# Excel find duplicate cells in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have an Excel table with 4 columns and need to find the values that are the same in ALL 4 of the columns and put them aside. Trying to figure out how to accomplish this in Excel.

Example:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
A1          B1          B1          A1
B1          C2          C1          B1
C2          D3          C2          C2
```

In this example, both **B1** and **C2** values comply and must be set aside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this formula in cell D1 and drag and drop it till the end of your values:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$3,A1)>0,COUNTIF($C$1:$C$3,A1)>0,COUNTIF($D$1:$D$3,A1)>0),A1,"not found")
```

For the record, the french version:

```
=SI(ET(NB.SI($B$1:$B$3;A1)>0;NB.SI($C$1:$C$3;A1)>0;NB.SI($D$1:$D$3;A1)>0);A1;"not found")
```

Comment: For clarification: perhaps you mean to enter in cell E1 and fill down, any values "Not Found" could then be filtered out.

Comment: I get "not found" on all cells.

Comment: are you sure you didn't make an error? I copied your example in my Excel 2007 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a list of values that appear in all four columns, try in cell F2:

`=INDEX(A$1:A$3,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(B$1:B$3,A$1:A$3)*COUNTIF(C$1:C$3,A$1:A$3)
*COUNTIF(D$1:D$3,A$1:A$3)*NOT(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,A$1:A$3))>0,0))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and fill down as far as needed (this assumes F1 is blank or contains unrelated data)

Comment: Rick - Be sure to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula otherwise and then fill down otherwise you will get a #N/A error.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the above examples to work for myself, so I came up with another solution.  Hopefully this will help someone else out there:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $B$2:$B$4, 0)), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $C$2:$C$4, 0)), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $D$2:$D$4, 0)), $A2, ""), ""), "")
```

This checks the value in "Column 1" ("A" column in excel) against the next 3 columns (B,C,D).  If the value is present in all three it returns the A column value.  If it is not present in all 3, it returns empty.  If you would rather return something else, put that something in between the empty quotation marks.

For your data, enter in the lengths of the searched columns, B through D.  For example, where it says,  "$B$4", put in "$B$99" if the cells go down to 99, but it should work if you put in a generically high number, for example, 99999.

Put this in the row of the first value, so here that would be E2, and then copy it down to every row that has a value in column A.

The function works by just nesting IF statements, and can be expanded or contracted depending on how many columns you want to check against.  The function can also be easily modified into a "check if in column B OR column C" function pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example for 1 value; I can't generalize since I did not see your data source

```
Sub test()
If (Range("D6").Value = Range("D6").Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
MsgBox "match"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can create a loop to match each valkue with other values; but again, I don't know what exactly you need to accomplish

Comment: this isn't what the OP wanted. He wants to check if the value occurs at least once in each column

Comment: Actually, the value must be on all 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can also delete duplicates across multiple Columns by using DATA-> Remove Duplicates.